# How to send messages when a customer is registered

Tags: api, user-registration

I am trying to send `MESSAGES` when a customer is

  Registered or he/she

  Reset his/her password

  Or any specific events that will be decided later .

I have an SMS API.

Suggest some step.

I just want to know how to trigger the API when a customer registered.
Is there any hook available by which i can trigger my custom function.

**UPDATE : My Problem is solved & Thank You @TomC**

```
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $registration_field_1 = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'registration_field_1', true );
    $smsDone = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'smsDone', true );

    if(!empty($smsDone) && $smsDone === 'True'){
    }else{
        $respuesta = wp_remote_get( "http://apiWebsite.com/messageapi.asp?username=key&password=somepwd@1&sender=key2&mobile=".$registration_field_1."&message=Your%20Profile%20is%20registered%20successfully%20.%20You%20are%20precious%20to%20us%20and%20we%20are%20glad%20to%20serve%20you%20better.%20Regards,%20The%20Astrochannel%20Team.");
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'smsDone','True'   ); 
    }
 }
```

I used this method to send the sms once a customer is registered.

Comment: Did you search at all? What have you tried and not working? Also by customer you imply that you are using an e-shop plugin like WooCommerce, right ? Please read [How to ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: is there any relation between woo commerce and sending SMS when any user registers themselves. Sorry, I am not getting your point.

Comment: It is because WooCommerce might have their actions and filters upon registration and mention it would help to get a better answer. For example `woocommerce_created_customer` action fires when a new customer is registered / created

Comment: well, seems like first you need a phone number to send the sms .... not sure what is exactly the answer you expect here, please edit the question and add actuall details not just highlights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about Wordpress user registration, you want to start by reading about the User Register hook: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

Then your code would be something like this which will automatically fire each time a user registers on the site:

```
add_action('user_register','send_sms');

function send_sms($user_id){
  // Code for your SMS API Here
}
```

The code would go in a plugin or in your Theme's `functions.php` file. 
If you're talking about an ecommerce plugin, you need to see what action hooks they have available for customer registration and use that as per the developer documentation.